# How do I "dump" an SVN remote repository that is being shut down

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

So we just got the notice that a number of our projects are being shut down that are currently hosted on [sourcerepo.com](http://sourcerepo.com).

Granted, that I could just update from the head revision and let everything be cool, for archival sake, I really would like to get the entire history of changes made to the repository over the past year and a half.

I came up with a quick and dirty solution that IS working, but is eating up disk space like crazy:

```
FOR /L %i IN (1, 1, 680) DO svn checkout <url>/Project@%i %i
SVN LOG <url>/Project >> log.txt
```

Even I don't like this!

`svnadmin dump <url>/Project` errored out, saying it required a local path to work with.

Is there a cleaner way to do this, even if I do not have local or SSH access to the server itself (I was only given read/write svn access over https, and can't even log into the site over the customer web portal)?

Comment: Do you need to have it in SVN locally or would you be amenable to use a more modern DVCS like git or mercurial? Both can import from SVN and might actually simplify the process.

Comment: @TimoGeusch I would love to migrate it over to git! We will be setting up an in-house server in the next couple months. However, I tried a git svn import last week on another personal project, and it did not pull in the full svn history into the git logs, making me think it probably would not be able to remember any of the previous revisions made over svn and revert to them if needed. Basically, I need to get a dump where I can look back through the entire history of changes made over the life of the project to see where it's been, how it began, and how much progress we've made on it.

Comment: My current plan is: do this weird 600+ looping checkout and manually (or batch-ly) re-push to the in-house server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After actually letting my computer run through my batch script detailed above, then doing a bit more research, I'm convinced that just migrating the whole thing to git was a good idea, and so I found this: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git

Basically, filled up a users.txt file with the five contributors, on per line, in the format `svn_username = Name <email>`.

I attempted the method they suggested of extracting users from the SVN log, but it did not work. So instead, I simply opened the SVN log in Tortoise, did a view all and quickly scanned through all the entries, then manually entered them into the text file..

Then performed `git clone https://<url>/Project --authors-file=users.txt --no-metadata Project` (did not use the `-s` flag, as the structure of our company project is not at all standard...).

It just plain worked. Started at r1 and went all the way up with no problem, save for a single "could not find this user in users.txt" which was easily fixed.

No tags or branches to speak of either, so none of that extra conversion was even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use svnsync:

```
svnsync help sync
synchronize (sync): usage: svnsync synchronize DEST_URL [SOURCE_URL]
```

Use git and do a clone **At rev 1**, then do a `pull` and an `update`.

Install `Mercurial`, install `hgsubversion` and enable it, do a clone **At rev 1**, then do a `pull` and an `update`.

As in both git and hg clone can error and leave you with nothing but pull can pick up where it left off/hit a problem it is usually a good plan to clone at rev 1 then pull/update.

You could even consider generating and storing patch files for each revision rather than the whole repository at each revision.

Answer (score 1):

The last two versions of Subversion include the [`svnrdump` tool](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html). Point at the URL for your repository and it'll produce a dumpfile which you can then use to load (`svnadmin load`) a local repository or use to convert to another VCS.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install python and pysvn *assuming that you don't have then already*.
2. Install svn admin tools on your local machine *assuming that you don't have then already*.
3. Create a local on your own machine repository and start a local server on it.
4. use a python script to pull each rev in turn from the remote server and the log entry for that rev.
5. commit each rev, with it's log message, to the local server.
6. When you are ready you can use the svnadmin tools to move from your own machine to a server that you have direct access to.